# Conflict between test with "given"

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

I have a feature test file that works fine when running alone. But, when I try to run all my tests, this same test returns me an error.

I was checking and I discovered that three files have an equal "given" and when I comment them, this test file works well.

This is the spec that is failing (file work_order_actions_spec.rb):

```
 feature "Work Order actions" do
  login_user

  given!(:client) { create(:client) }
  given!(:location) { create(:location, client: client) }
  given!(:contract) { create(:contract, client: client) }
  given!(:work_orders) { create_list :work_order, 3, client: client, contract: contract, location: location }
  given!(:other_work_orders) { create_list :work_order, 2 }

  ...

  context "open a new work_order" do
    given!(:responsible) { create(:user) }
    given!(:work_order) { attributes_for :work_order }

    scenario "with valid information should open successfully with :waiting_for_service status", js: true do
      visit work_orders_path
      all(".open_work_order").first.click
      expect(page).to_not have_css "#work_order_status"
      fill_in "work_order_opening_date", with: work_order[:opening_date]
      fill_in "work_order_service_description", with: work_order[:service_description]
      select_by_value work_order[:urgency], from: "work_order_urgency"
      select client.id, from: "work_order_client"
      select location.id, from: "work_order_location"
      select contract.id, from: "work_order_contract"
      select responsible.id, from: "work_order_responsible_id"
      find("input[type='submit']").click
      work_order = WorkOrder.last
      expect(page).to have_current_path work_order_path(work_order)
      expect(page).to have_content work_order.status_text
      expect(page).to have_content i18n_notice_responder(:create, WorkOrder)
    end
```

This is the "given" that is presence on one of these three files (file contract_actions_spec.rb):

```
feature "Contract actions" do
  login_user

  given(:client) { create(:client) }
  given!(:contracts) { create_list :contract, 5, client: client }
  given!(:other_contracts) { create_list :contract, 5 }
  ...
end
```

If I comment this "given(:client)" on my file contract_actions_spec.rb, the tests on work_orders_spec.rb works well. This tests also works if I put work_orders_spec.rb to run first, all works well too.

This is an error view:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftEBE.png)

This is the section on attempting to select the field. There is a Ajax here. When the Client is selected, the field Contract is filled using Ajax. Out of testing and without another conflict test (as contract_actions_spec.rb), it works well.

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group select required work_order_client">
    <label class="control-label select required" for="work_order_client">
      <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Client
    </label>
    <select class="form-control select required" id="work_order_client" data-location-url="/clients/:client_id/locations" data-contract-url="/clients/:client_id/contracts" name="work_order[client_id]">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="892">Client 891</option>
      <option value="893">Client 892</option>
      <option value="894">Client 893</option>
      <option value="895">Client 894</option>
      <option value="896">Client 895</option>
      <option value="897">Client 896</option>
      <option value="898">Client 897</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group select required work_order_contract">
    <label class="control-label select required" for="work_order_contract">
      <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Contract
    </label>
    <select class="form-control select required" id="work_order_contract" name="work_order[contract_id]"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

On this project, I'm using Docker and Selenium is a container and I configured Capybara to use this remote Selenium

```
if ENV['SELENIUM_REMOTE_HOST']
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_remote_firefox
  Capybara.register_driver "selenium_remote_firefox".to_sym do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :remote,
      url: "http://#{ENV['SELENIUM_REMOTE_HOST']}:4444/wd/hub",
      desired_capabilities: :firefox)
  end

  ip = `/sbin/ip route|awk '/scope/ { print $9 }'`
  ip = ip.gsub "\n", ""
  Capybara.server_port = "3000"
  Capybara.server_host = ip
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{Capybara.server_host}:#{Capybara.server_port}"
end
```

On the container where tests run, ENV['SELENIUM_REMOTE_HOST'] have the value 'selenium' (name o of my container with Selenium)

Comment: Can you add the relevant section of HTML at the time of attempting to select the contract id to the questions (`puts page.html` should output it)

Comment: HTML section added.

Comment: Ok - so the error is correct for the HTML shown since there are no contracts to select.  Check your test.log to see if the ajax request for the list of contracts is sent, and what parameters are passed.  Also, what driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: I only do a request on a URL with this format `/clients/:client_id/contracts` without any additional params and it calls an index action on my ContractsController and renders a JSON. I checked my logs and on both cases, when I have success and when I have an error, the requests are been sent. I'm using Selenium.

Comment: I don't know if it impacts, but I'm using docker on my project and my Selenium is a container of the image "standalone-firefox". I also added my Capybara configs on problem description.

Comment: Where are you switching to the `javascript_driver`?  You have an after block that resets to the default driver, so have you set that to `:selenium_remote_firefox` or are you switching each test to the `javascript_driver` some other way (I don't see any metadata on the tests)?  If it was using the wrong driver it would explain it only working when run as the first test, but it wouldn't explain your claim of failures making the ajax request.  Also, when you comment out the `given(:client)` in the other tests I assume they then fail?

Comment: Also, are you using Rails 5 or 5.1? If 5 are you using database cleaner?

Comment: I wasn't setting my javascript_drive on another. I tried to remove those before hooks and use Capybara config out of it, but the same error still ocurring. I'm using Rails 5.1 with database_cleaner.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand from that statement exactly what you're doing.  Try setting `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_remote_firefox` and see what happens.   Note, that since you're on Rails 5.1 you can probably remove database_cleaner and just enable transactional tests.

Comment: I tried to set default_drive as you told and after it, a lot of tests of mine also began to fail. Well, if you have a material talking about remote selenium, I can try it.

Comment: I just tried another config to avoid that RSpec _before_ hook and the error still ocurring. I updated problem description to show it. What is strange is: when I run my file work_order_actions_spec.rb with another one, like contract_item_actions_spec.rb, nothing fails. The tests of file work_order_actions_spec is failing only when I run it with specific files. When I comment that _given_ that I saw on problem, this test works well. Is there a way to avoid a _given_ in one file to interfer on another test file?

Comment: a given in one shouldn't interfere with another -- You didn't answer my previous question - when you comment out the given in the one file, do the tests in that file then fail?

Comment: Also -- I have no idea why you're removing the before hook -- I asked you to try setting `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_remote_firefox`  (not `default_drive` and you have already registered the :selenium_remote_firefox driver), and tell me what happens then (with the tests that were failing, new failures would be irrelevanat) - and I have no idea what `if you have a material talking about remote selenium` means.

Comment: Maybe just post your ENTIRE Capybara  and database_cleaner config (everything that mention capybara or database_cleaner in it) rather than bits and pieces.

Comment: When I set  `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_remote_firefox` this test still failing.
Now the error is:
    `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
            Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.`

Comment: none of this makes any sense - You are registering the `:selenium_remote_firefox` driver and stated that it works -- however if you're getting that error then you don't have geckodriver installed which means the driver never could have worked in the first place.  I give up.